# scala & Spark - ArrayBuffer does not append

Tags: scala, collections, apache-spark, tuples, arraybuffer

I am new to Scala and Apache Spark and have been trying out some online examples.

I am using scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer to store a list of tuples of the form (Int,Array[String]). I am creating an ArrayBuffer and then parsing a text file line by line and appending the required data from each line to the ArrayBuffer.

The code has no compilation errors. But when I access ArrayBuffer outside the block where I am appending it, I am not able to get the contents and the ArrayBuffer is always empty.

My code is below -

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("second")
val spark = new SparkContext(conf)

val file = spark.textFile("\\Desktop\\demo.txt")
var list = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[(Int, Array[String])]()
var count = 0

file.map(_.split(","))
.foreach { a =>
count = countByValue(a) // returns an Int
println("count is " + count) // showing correct output "count is 3"
var t = (count, a)
println("t is " + t) // showing correct output "t is (3,[Ljava.lang.String;@539f0af)"
list += t
}

println("list count is = " + list.length) // output "list count is = 0"
list.foreach(println) // no output
```

Can someone point out why this code isn't working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `spark` is a `SparkContext`. In this case this is not surprising that the local `list` is not updated, only its copy sent to spark as a closure. In case you need a mutable value within the `foreach`, you should use an [`Accumulator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.Accumulator).

Comment: I should add that the `ArrayBuffer`'s `+=` is not associative, so you need to modify your requirements or use something else.

Comment: Thank you.
spark is a SparkContext. I have edited the code to make it more clear. I will try to use a custom Accumulator for the ArrayBuffer.
Can you suggest any other alternative to += ?

Comment: No, in a reduce (accumulation) phase the order of reduce is not defined, so the values could be in any order. Probably if you `zipWithIndex` the original RDD and use that info as an additional tuple value you can resort the output from the accumulator to keep the original order.

Comment: (`++` is associative for `ArrayBuffer`s, so probably with this is doable after all. Sorry, it is quite late here.)

Comment: Since i do not want the values to be in order, I created a custom Accumulator for the ArrayBuffer and I used the ++ for ArrayBuffer in the addInPlace method of the accumulator. I am now able to get the contents of the ArrayBuffer after the foreach block.